# Can't display highchart with my json data

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, highcharts

I am using highchart to draw the graph, but there's a problem that I can't draw the graph when I tried to replace the URL of `$.getJSON('URL', function (data))` to 
`$.getJSON('Highchart_getData.php', function (data)` there's nothing displayed.
I choose this example

> http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/flags-placement/

Then I want to connect my mysql data to draw the graph.

JS.javascript:

```
$.getJSON('Highchart_getData.php', function (data) {

var lastDate = data[data.length - 1][0],  // Get year of last data point
    days = 24 * 36e5; // Milliseconds in a day

// Create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: '光照量歷史圖表'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: '單位:Lux'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: '當日光照量',
        data: data,
        id: 'dataseries',
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 4
        }
    }, {
        type: 'flags',
        name: 'Flags on series',
        data: [{
            x: lastDate - 60 * days,
            title: 'On series'
        }, {
            x: lastDate - 30 * days,
            title: 'On series'
        }],
        onSeries: 'dataseries',
        shape: 'squarepin'
    }, {
        type: 'flags',
        name: 'Flags on axis',
        data: [{
            x: lastDate - 45 * days,
            title: 'On axis'
        }, {
            x: lastDate - 15 * days,
            title: 'On axis'
        }],
        shape: 'squarepin'
}]
});
});
```

Highchart_getData.php:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
$hostdb = "localhost";  
$userdb = "root";  
$passdb = "";  
$namedb = "light_care";  
$dbhandle = new mysqli($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb, $namedb);
if ($dbhandle->connect_error) {
exit("There was an error with your connection: ".$dbhandle->connect_error);
}

include("mysql_connect.inc.php");
$id=$_SESSION['username'];
$today= date('Y')-2000;
$today .= date('-m-d');
$arrData = array();
if($_SESSION['username'] != null)   
{

        $sqlID = "select * from user where username='$id'";
        $resultID = mysql_query($sqlID);

            $userID=array();
            if($resultID === FALSE) { 
                die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
            }

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultID))
            {
                $userID[0]=$row["ID"];              
            }

for( $a=0;$a<30;$a++)
{   
    $date= date('Y')-2000;
    $date .= date('-m-d',time()-24*60*60*$a);
    //$date= date('Y-m-d',time()-24*60*60*$a); 
    $sql = "select * from data where user_id='$userID[0]' and data_time like 
'%$date%'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $light=array();
    //echo $date;   

        $count=0;
        $light_sum=0;
        $step_sum=0;
    if($result === FALSE) { 
            die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    }

            $lsum=array();
            $ssum=array();
            $Data=0;

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {               

            $Date=$row["data_time"];
            $Data+=$row["light"];
            //$light_sum+=$Data[$count];
            //$DATE=$Data[$count];


            $count++;

        }
        //echo $date;
        $date= date('Y');
        $date .= date('-m-d',time()-24*60*60*$a);
        $DATA[0]=$date;
        $DATA[1]=$Data;

        array_push($arrData,$DATA);
        $light_sum=0;

}

            /*JSON Encode the data to retrieve the string containing the 
JSON representation of the data in the array. */

            $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($arrData);

            print($jsonEncodedData);


             //Close the database connection
            $dbhandle->close();
        }
//  }
?>
```

and the ouput is:

```
[["2017-07-20",0],["2017-07-19",0],["2017-07-18",562],["2017-07-17",746],["2017-07-16",0],["2017-07-15",0],["2017-07-14",0],["2017-07-13",0],["2017-07-12",0],["2017-07-11",0],["2017-07-10",0],["2017-07-09",0],["2017-07-08",0],["2017-07-07",0],["2017-07-06",0],["2017-07-05",0],["2017-07-04",0],["2017-07-03",0],["2017-07-02",0],["2017-07-01",0],["2017-06-30",0],["2017-06-29",0],["2017-06-28",0],["2017-06-27",0],["2017-06-26",0],["2017-06-25",0],["2017-06-24",0],["2017-06-23",0],["2017-06-22",0],["2017-06-21",0]]
```

JQ.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-
3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS.js"></script>
</html>
```

but there's nothing being displayed :(
I have struggle for many days, but it still can't work...
Is there anyone can help me .
Thank you very much! and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Avoid to use `mysql` for security reason. Use `mysqli` OR `PDO`.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the dev console?

Comment: no, there's no error on console

Comment: When you say nothing do you mean not even the chart axis? Or is there just no data shown on the chart?

Comment: there's a blank page :(

Comment: The HTML and JavaScript you have provided works fine https://jsfiddle.net/cgr6wcLp/ so there must be something missing. Are you sure this is the final rendered HTML?

Comment: oh, it seems the date need to change to the Date.UTC(2013,5,2) format.

Comment: but in my browser there's blank . I think it maybe some error in  php

Comment: may I ask you how to change the format from ["2017-07-20",0] to [Date.UTC(2013,10,4),0.7399]  ><

Comment: You don't really need to call [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) unless you want to convert the times to UTC. Your data is mostly 0 which is why the chart is empty in the fiddle.

Comment: yes, but the graph only support the Date format.